# How to change the regional decimal setting symbol from "," to be"." with batch-file?

Tags: batch-file

The problem :
In the same script, I extract data from a sql database with the decimal symbol "." then I use an external program (exe command line) which only starts with the regional setting on decimal "," or in france the standard is "."

Is there a command line with a batch-file to change the decimal symbol of windows before calling the external program and then restore it?

This is the manuel method :
Step 1: Click the bottom-left Start button on desktop, type currency in the search box and tap Change the way currency is displayed.
Step 2: Open Additional settings in the Region window.
Step 3: On "Formats", change the decimal symbol to "," then click OK.

Comment: I'd suggest a little less vagueness would be prudent.

Comment: Hello, I have edited my post, now that the subject is more explicit, you may be the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, and not without difficulty, I found a solution, it's worth what it's worth, but it works!

My procedure for a switch in batch :

```
@ECHO OFF
SET registreChemin=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International
SET registreCle=sDecimal
SET registreType=REG_SZ
SET registreValeurVirgule=,
SET registreValeurPoint=.
REG QUERY "%registreChemin%" /v "%registreCle%" | FIND "%registreValeurPoint%"
CLS
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 GOTO ADD_POINT
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO ADD_VIRGULE
:ADD_VIRGULE
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /f /v "sDecimal" /t %registreType% /d "%registreValeurVirgule%"
CLS
ECHO Separateur decimal ","
GOTO END
:ADD_POINT
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /f /v "sDecimal" /t %registreType% /d "%registreValeurPoint%"
CLS
ECHO Separateur decimal "."
GOTO END
:END
PAUSE
```